# Collection group by and concatenate specific column LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have the following response:

```
#items: array:4 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "taskID" => "5"
      "title" => "Idea for the Project"
      "resource" => "Fac - Architect"
      "start" => "Wed Jul 31 08:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "finish" => "Wed Jul 31 17:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "predecessors" => "-"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "taskID" => "5"
      "title" => "Idea for the Project"
      "resource" => "Fac - PM"
      "start" => "Wed Jul 31 08:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "finish" => "Wed Jul 31 17:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "predecessors" => "-"
    ]
    2 => array:6 [▼
      "taskID" => "5"
      "title" => "Idea for the Project"
      "resource" => "King"
      "start" => "Wed Jul 31 08:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "finish" => "Wed Jul 31 17:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "predecessors" => "-"
    ]
    3 => array:6 [▼
      "taskID" => "5"
      "title" => "Idea for the Project"
      "resource" => "Stakeholder"
      "start" => "Wed Jul 31 08:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "finish" => "Wed Jul 31 17:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "predecessors" => "-"
    ]
  ]
```

I want to group those array's into one array and concatenate the resource names like the following:

```
#items: array:4 [▼
      "taskID" => "5"
      "title" => "Idea for the Project"
      "resource" => [
          "Fac - Architect",
          "Second Resource",
           ...
        ],
      "start" => "Wed Jul 31 08:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "finish" => "Wed Jul 31 17:00:00 EEST 2019"
      "predecessors" => "-"

  ]
```

Any help?
And if it could be done in a way using collections or array functions without the need of using many for loops that would be great.
I'm using Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but you can do something like this

```php
<?php

$items = collect(YOUR_RESPONSE);
$firstItem = $items->shift();
$firstItem['resource'] = [$firstItem['resource']];

$items->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry['resource'][] = $item['resource'];
    return $carry;
}, $firstItem);
```

Then `$items->all()` would give you what you want.